# Set order for colours in gpl colour palette in Inkscape

Tags: color, inkscape, palette

I was able to create a *.gpl* file colour palette which is working fine with Inkscape. Sadly, the colours auto arranged themselves in some funny order. Probably from `ffffff` to `000000`. All I had to do was create rectangles of desired hex colours and then save as *.gpl* using Inkscape. Now that I have placed the *.gpl* file in the palette folder and restarted Inkscape, all the colours are available when I choose the palette by name, sadly, in a messed up order. It will be great if someone can suggest a fix. Thanks.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and whatever the latest Inkscape that comes with it.

Please see the image below for the order in which I have stacked the colours and how it ended up appearing on the palette

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an Inkscape extension that generators a palette from the selected objects.

- [Inkscape Generate Palette](https://github.com/olibia/inkscape-generate-palette) on GitHub
- [Generate Palette Extension](https://inkscape.org/%7Eolibia/%E2%98%85generate-palette-extension) on inkscape.org

1. First install the extension – see [README](https://github.com/olibia/inkscape-generate-palette/blob/master/README.md) with options/instructions.
2. Restart Inkscape.
3. Use the extension by selecting your palette objects then open `Extensions → Palette → generate`
4. Name the palette, select your sorting method and click Apply.

[image: generate palette Gui]

It has five sorting options:

- "Unsorted" was renamed to "Selection/Z-Index" in `v6.0+`
- HSL
- RGB
- X Location `v6.0+`
- Y Location `v6.0+`

"Unsorted"/"Selection/z-index" sorts the palette first by the order the object where selected and second by the z-index.

[image: sort by selection z-index]

## UPDATE:

I contributed to the extension.

In Inscape Generate Palette [version 6.0](https://github.com/olibia/inkscape-generate-palette/releases/tag/v6.0) you can sort your palette by the x or y canvas location. Arranging a palette by the z-index is no longer necessary.

Instead arrange your palette in the x or y order, and select 'Sort colors' by the `X Location` or `Y Location`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is possible inside Inkscape, but if you open the .gpl file in a text editor it's actually readable and easy to edit. Here is an example:

```
GIMP Palette
Name: drawing
#
153 153 153 #999999
  0 128   0 #008000
211 141  95 #D38D5F
255   0   0 #FF0000
255 127  42 #FF7F2A
```

The first three columns are the RGB values of the colors. The fourth column is the name of the color which will show in Inkscape when hovering over the swatch. It's set to the colors hex number by default, but it can be edited to whatever you like without affecting the color.

To change the order of the colors simply edit the order they appear in the .gpl file.

Comment: Thanks. It should work. However, will be tedious if you have many entries. Trying to find a GUI based solution. Any idea what the 3 entries before hex codes are ?

Comment: It's the same colors represented with RGB values. Kinda strange to save both in the file. I don't know what happens if you edit the values so the hex and RGB values don't match anymore ...

Comment: The colours are defined by the rgb values in the first three columns. The 4th column is used as name for hovering over the colour

Comment: @samcarter, thanks. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: I am still looking for a GUI based fix.

Comment: I understand. You will probably need some kind of plugin which adds an interface where you can move the colors around. I understand why Inkscape can't guess which order you want the colors in based on your drawing.